# Joining two tables in QlikView

Tags: qlikview

Need to join `CountPerCategory` from resident table after applying `count` function to another table (`FACT`)

```
FOR Each vsheet2 IN 'D','H','Q'
    FACT:
    LOAD
        RowNo() as ID,
        ProfileReceivedDate,
    "SkillCategory ";
    SQL SELECT
        ProfileReceivedDate,
        "SkillCategory "
    FROM .dbo.$(vsheet2);
NEXT

FOR Each vsheet3 In 'D','H','Q'
    SKILL_CATEGORIES:
    LOAD
        "SkillCategory ";
    SQL SELECT
        "SkillCategory "
    FROM Ndbo.$(vsheet3);
NEXT

JOIN (vsheet2):
countSkill:
Load
    Count("SkillCategory ") as CountPerCategory
Resident
    SKILL_CATEGORIES
Group by
    "SkillCategory "
;
```

Comment: In skill category , there are records like technician,tester,coder etc. So i need to get the count of individual records in skill category

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in general?

Comment: You're not selecting any keys between the tables so no proper joins are possible

Answer (score 0):

Left join the secondary table to the FACT table via LEFT JOIN([Table Name]) and ensure you apply the "SkillCategory " field to the GROUP BY also if that is how you are linking the values.

Thanks

```html
FOR Each vsheet2 IN 'D','H','Q'
    FACT:
    LOAD
        RowNo() as ID,
        ProfileReceivedDate,
    "SkillCategory ";
    SQL SELECT
        ProfileReceivedDate,
        "SkillCategory "
    FROM .dbo.$(vsheet2);
NEXT

FOR Each vsheet3 In 'D','H','Q'
    SKILL_CATEGORIES:
    LOAD
        "SkillCategory ";
    SQL SELECT
        "SkillCategory "
    FROM Ndbo.$(vsheet3);
NEXT

LEFT JOIN(FACT)
Load
    "SkillCategory ",
    Count("SkillCategory ") as CountPerCategory
Resident
    SKILL_CATEGORIES
Group by
    "SkillCategory ";
```